# FindInstance of Matrix elements with dictionary

Tags: matrix, dictionary

I'm a complete beginner at Mathematica, I'm trying to find a matrix A which when squared gives a specific solution. The elements of matrix A are k-th roots of unity (which I will specify), or if there is no solution, their absolute value should be 1.

Below is my attemp at the problem:

```
c = IdentityMatrix[10]*10 - Reverse[IdentityMatrix[10]*6];
A = Array[x, {10, 10}];
FindInstance[A^2 == c && Abs[x] == 1, x];
```

This does not work with the error indInstance::exvar: "The system contains a nonconstant expression x[1,1] independent of variables {x}.
1. How should I specify a dictionary, i.e. the k-th roots of unity?
2. How to fix the error?

Comment: your `c` is just `IdentityMatrix[10]*16`, so the answer is `(IdentityMatrix[10]*4)`

Comment: It's actually in a X shape, non-zero elements on the diagonal and flipped diagonal. Sorry for the trouble, I've corrected the code

Comment: 1. Avoid capitalized variables, as these may conflict with builtins. 2. `m^2` is elementwise square. `m.m` is matrix square. 3. If you use `x[1,1]` as a symbolic variable, you can't also use `x`. You probably wanted to specify `Abs[...]==1` for *each* `x[i,j]` separately, and then again specify them separately in FindInstance.  That's 100 symbolic variables.  That's too many and you won't get a solution in a reasonable time.

Comment: But I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no answer:

Set up, and define all variables used:

```
c = IdentityMatrix[10]*10 - Reverse[IdentityMatrix[10]*6];
A = Array[x, {10, 10}];
eqs = Thread[Map[Abs, vars = Variables[A]] == 1];
```

This works, as can be seen here:

```
s = FindInstance[A^2 == c, vars][[1]];
Simplify[(A^2 /. s) == c]
```

> `True`

However, with the additional stipulation that the absolute values of all elements are `1`, no solution presents itself:

```
s = FindInstance[Join[{A^2 == c}, eqs], vars]
```

> `{}`